# Umbraco Page redirect Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I am developing a `Umbraco` Website using `ASP.NET MVC 5.0`. Following is the structure of the website

```
Home 
    Page 1
    Page 2
    ...
```

**C1, C2**  are properties shared by all the pages(**Home, Page 1, Page 2**).
**H1, H2** are **Home Page** properties. 
**P1, P2** are properties of **Page 1 and Page 2**.

So I created document types and Content in the following way

```
Root (C1, C2)
    Home (H1, H2)
    Page 1(P1, P2)
    Page 2(P1, P2)
```

The reason I created **Root document type** and content is to put the common properties **C1 and C2**.
If I use **Home Page** instead of **Root** then **H1 and H2** properties appear on **Page 1 and Page 2**.

But the problem in the above structure is that I have to redirect **Root** to **Home page**. SEO tools doesn't like it.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What are those shared properties? One possible solution is to put them in the Homepage node and in the Page1 and Page2 get them from the homepage

Answer (score 1):

What you've done is a legitimate approach to building an Umbraco website. I tend to see one of two approaches:

1. The user creates the Home node as their uppermost node. In addition to this, the user creates a Global node next to the Home node. They store site-side settings either on Global or in a Settings node underneath. Personally, I prefer this approach, but that's just me.
2. The user creates a Root node as their uppermost node. Underneath the root node they add a Home node, where all home content comes from.

I'm guessing that your issue is that you want the root node to load your home page data. This is easily done by adding a property to your Document Type with the alias [umbracoInternalRedirectId](https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-best-practices/umbracointernalredirectid/). Set this to be a Content Picker, pick your home page, and when you load the root node in your browser you'll see the home page contents.

Answer (score 0):

The document structure is fine. But you don't need a content node called Root, Home should be at the top of the tree. Make sure that on the Home document type, under Permissions, you have ticked Yes - allow content of this type in the root